# CouchDB/PouchDB selector for deleted docs

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying to use a selector in sync() from remote CouchDB to local PouchDB for filtering out deleted documents:

```
selector: {
  _deleted: {
    $ne: true
  }
}
```

It doesn't return any documents from sync. How can I sync only non-deleted docs using selector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use $exists

```
selector: {
  _deleted: {
    $exists: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip! To elaborate, the *reason* this works (afaict) is that contrary to the documentation's summary (https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.0/api/database/find.html#condition-operators) the "$ne" operand seems to actually mean "The field [exists, and] is not equal to the argument." So in documents where the `_deleted` field [or any other field, whether built-in or user-defined!] is absent, the $ne will not match.